# Small utility to generate SSHA passwords?

Tags: security, password-manager, offline

I am looking for a small cross-platform utility that I can recommend people use to generate salted SHA1 digest passwords suitable for use with OpenLDAP. The utility should:

- Not require installing or any options to run
- Not transmit the password over the wire in any form
- Enforce some basic password quality rules
- Generate a hash compatible with those made with [`slappasswd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/slappasswd)

Installing OpenLDAP, enough of a Unix environment to run `slappasswd`, or even just the tools needed to SSH to a remote host on random customer's Windows or Mac computers just to generate them a password is too much work. What is a simpler option? Is there a [puttygen](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen) equivalent for hashed passwords?

Comment: Having done a bit of searching I pretty much gave up hope that something existed already so I sat down and [wrote a Javascript based one](https://iguana.alerque.com/slappasswd.html) this afternoon. If no answers turn up to this question I may package that up as a single downloadable html page for offline use and release it somewhere.

Comment: I happened to write down an answer for this question, while I was actually answering to you with your own tool. Heh, sorry for that. Would you be ok with me republishing that work as a npm module? I think it might be of use to the community.

Comment: @Alpha If it would be generally useful as a stand alone module I think I'd rather publish it myself that way, probably as AGPL. Would that suit your usage?

Comment: Yes, it would. What we need is everything that you did plus: easily accessible offline, simple code to assess security and what it actually does, easily executable from command line. I thought a simple js file (+ dependencies) and console output would fit that, so I imagined npm might fit the bill.

Comment: @Alpha It sounds like you want too many things from one package. Local browser UI (are you thinking SPA style or local server?) + CLI is not a good fit for one package. The code of that page is only a couple lines, and uses two libraries already in npm to do all the heavy lifting. There is also a package for getting these hashes from the CLI (but without entropy enforcement). If there was a clear spec for what you wanted I'd write it, but right now it seems kind of all over the place.

Comment: I wasn't thinking in local server, just a local CLI. In short, I want to replicate slappasswd in node.

Comment: @Alpha So why not just use [sshapw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sshapw)?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. That's exactly what I need. Thank you very much. :) I'll edit my answer and add it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is fairly old, but I reached it by looking for a tool with those specific requirements.

I ended up at this web implementation: https://iguana.alerque.com/slappasswd.html

- It's web, so any browser with JavaScript is enough to generate passwords
- There is no storage or transmission of the password, the hashing is done completely offline (at least in the time of writing)
- The hashed password displays different colours according to the complexity and entropy of the password entered. Even particular sequences (like `123`) are counted so that they don't add complexity because they are very easy to predict.
- It creates a password that can be imported into OpenLDAP servers

---

If you're willing to use an offline version but still cross-platform, you can use [sshapw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sshapw), only with npm installed:

```
$ npm install -g sshapw
$ sshapw
password: <entered password>
repeat password: <entered password>
{SSHA}8MLTTuGYsxWFaj6vn3nUh1o5l5c4Q7K/Zx5LvwTfaYdvZ2UZ+B10tlBqvxihOCFxFTh8rQ==
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html). It contains many different ways and also other link(s) to generate {SHA} and {SSHA} password. For my use case, i only needed {SHA} password, so this was enough for me:

> The below batch script can generate a {SHA} hash suitable for LDAP
> passwords:
>
> makeshahash.bat: 
> @echo off 
> echo|set /p="{SHA}" 
> echo|set /p="%1" |
> openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64
>
> makeshahash.bat secret
> {SHA}5en6G6MezRroT3XKqkdPOmY/BfQ=